# Problems using package 'minet' - could not find function mutinformation

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, bioconductor

When trying to run the sample code that is in the Minet paper / vignette I am experiencing a nunber of issues, e.g.

```
mim <- build.mim(discretize(syn.data), estimator)

Error in build.mim(dataset, estimator, disc, nbins):
    could not find function "mutinformation"
```

I have also received other errors such as "unknown estimator" when trying methods prefixed with "mi." e.g. "mi.empirical."

I am running windows 8.1. Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT 1: Additional Information**

After playing around some more, the main problem I am having is when trying to use the *discretize* function like so:

```
> data(syn.data)
> disc <- "equalwidth"
> nbins <- sqrt(nrow(syn.data))
> ew.data <- discretize(syn.data, disc, nbins)

Error: could not find function "discretize"
```

This causes the same Error in all functions e.g. build.mim or minet which utilise discretize. I can run build.mim successfully without including discretize.

In addition, I am getting errors if I use minet (whilst excluding the discretize argument) with any of the mi.* estimation methods, e.g.

```
> res<-minet(syn.data,"mrnet","mi.empirical","equal width",10)
Error in build.mim(dataset, estimator, disc, nbins) : 
  could not find function "mutinformation"
```

However, running the same function with the "spearman" estimator works fine.

**Edit 2: Output of sessionInfo()**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] minet_3.20.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: Please post all the commands you are trying and their output (for example, how syn.data and estimator are constructed) and post the output of sessionInfo().

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. Ive added some more information above. Let me know if I have missed anything!

Comment: Hey Dan - any love for this question? I suspect this is just me not doing something right, but any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

discretize() is a function from the package infotheo that you can find in CRAN. There are some references to that package in the minet documentation. Maybe the authors of minet have moved some functionality to the infotheo package but since it is not a dependency it does not get installed automatically. It may be worth contacting the authors about this.

```
library(infotheo)
data(syn.data)
disc <- "equalwidth"
nbins <- sqrt(nrow(syn.data))
ew.data <- discretize(syn.data, disc, nbins)
```

The same applies for the multiinformation() function(). It is part of the infotheo package.

Comment: Yup. I was going to answer this myself but I forgot, and as you have now supplied the solution that I came to I will mark this correct. Being new to R I was under the impression that all of the dependencies would be installed (and usually they are, under normal circumstances). However, using the `biocLite("minet")` installation method left me without several key packages, most notably `infotheo` as mentioned above. Make sure you have all the dependencies noted [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/minet.html). including all those for each of the `depends on me` links.

Comment: Yep, it is surprising- I found myself two weeks ago when trying to use `minet`. I will email the maintainer so that he can fix the problem.

Comment: I meant to ask above whether you have any experience with minet on large datasets? Im interested in how long it took you to run it if so.